# Конвертация изображения в png (PHP)

Tags: php, png, конвертация

Как средствами php конвертировать изображения (.jpg, jpeg, gif) в png ? Если кто знает дайте пример

Comment: Alex Belyaev дал достаточно раскрытый ответ. можете закрывать вопрос

Comment: извините показалось, что поставил ответ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поможет [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php):

```
imagepng(
    imagecreatefromstring(
        file_get_contents($filename)
    ), 
    "output.png"
);
```